# How to enable UISearchBar grey out view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

I am using a UISearchBar and once the user taps the bar (and the keyboard pops up) I want the everything besides the keyboard and UISearchBar to be greyed out. Similar to safari when the search is selected. I do not need past searches. See here:

[image: Safari showing greyed out field]

Anyone have any ideas? I've looked through the questions here on StackOverflow and I can't find anything specific.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView how to "dim" the actual table when UISearchbar gets focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218461/uitableview-how-to-dim-the-actual-table-when-uisearchbar-gets-focus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `UIView` that contains the `UISearchBar`. And then you can set `UIView`'s `backgroundColor` to get the gray background.

And here's some sample code:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
[view1 addSubview:searchBar];
[searchBar release];

[self.window addSubview:view1];
[view1 release];
```